# Need some Mysql help and suggestion regarding order import via CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am going to create a module in a website where i can save orders offline through CSV import, so my question is while importing orders into MySql. If someone(user) make orders via checkout process...will this effect the order table?

Sorry if i am making silly question?

Thanks,
Mohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are thinking about the performance during this time then, it doesn't have any problem in case of InnoDB storage engine. It provide row level locking strategy. for more you need to go through locking in innodb for simultaneous inserts. INSERT sets an exclusive ... [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html). So your online checkout process will continue to work.

For MyIsam it create wait until the load statement complete, Till that time your online check out process will wait and continue after load statement finish.